# javascript: match string with placeholders

Tags: javascript, regex, placeholder

I want to check if my string "Hello my name is Thomas" matches with the string "Hello my name is $".
So for me following statement should be true:

```
"Hello my name is Thomas" == "Hello my name is $"
```

afterwards i want to extract the $ string something like

```
function getParam(text, template) {
  returns "Thomas"
}
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a regex, then retrieve the data using `Regex.exec`

```js
const regex = /Hello my name is (.*)/;

const ret = regex.exec('Hello my name is thomas');

console.log(ret[1]);
```

---

When using regex, you can use of https://regex101.com/. it helps you understand what you are doing.

Example in your case :

[image]

---

---

```js
function extractName(str) {
  const ret = /Hello my name is (.*)/.exec(str);

  return (ret && ret[1].trim()) || null;
}

const name = extractName('Hello my name is thomas');

const nameWithSpace = extractName('Hello my name is    thomas    ');

const fail = extractName('failure');

console.log(name);
console.log(nameWithSpace);
console.log(fail);
```

Comment: When no match is found the function should better return `null` as opposed to `false` - makes it more sensible IMO.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Why not :) The important thing is its not a string

Comment: Since [*exec*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Return_value) returns `null` itself when no match is found. I would return it early using a guard, then proceed to handle the match. `if (!ret) return ret;` But this is just personal preference.